# Flutter app on Android issue - problem occurred evaluating root project 'android

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm having issues running a Flutter app on an Android device. Note that is is working as expected on an IOS emulator. Is there anyone here that might have an idea what could be the issue?

Emulator: Pixel XL API 22 (android-x86 emulator) running on Macbook Pro.

Here is the error that I get when I run the following commands:

Command: `flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run`
Output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myapp/myapp/android/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 944ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,486ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Below are additional info for more context.

If I enter in the terminal gradle -v it outputs:

```
Gradle 8.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2024-03-22 15:52:46 UTC
Revision:     650af14d7653aa949fce5e886e685efc9cf97c10

Kotlin:       1.9.22
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          21.0.2 (Homebrew 21.0.2)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.3.1 x86_64
```

Android Studio Project Structure settings:
[image]

Here is my build.gradle file (flutter_project_root_folder->android->build.gradle)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.myapp.app.myapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Here is what I have already tried:
In Android Studio:

1. clean the project
2. go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" check all boxes and restart

Also tried adding the following code to my build.gradle file without success:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() 
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution could be copy your lib folder code in a new flutter project and your pubspec dependencies and try to do a

```
flutter pub get
```

the new flutter app in which you copy your code shouldn't have an issue. There are surely better ways to solve it but if you lack time you can go for it.